# Double Citizen (TR & US) going to Cyprus

Tags: customs-and-immigration, dual-nationality, cyprus, northern-cyprus

I have a US passport and Turkish ID. I've been to TRNC before where I can enter and stay 90 days with my Turkish ID, no problems.

Now, I want to travel there with my friend who is Dutch and we want to enter from Netherlands to ROC, then cross to North. (So, my aim is to go to TRNC, but I found very affordable tickets to the ROC.)

Here is my question: If I enter as an American from ROC and cross to TRNC, what is my status when I stay in TRNC? If I travel to Turkey with my Turkish ID, what would be the case of my entry with my US passport?

It's a bit confusing, but I'm trying to figure out the most suitable way without entry issues.

I'd be very glad if anyone here help me find answers.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Most countries provide that if a traveler leaves without getting an exit stamp or having their departure otherwise recorded that they can use other evidence to establish when they left.  If you enter Turkey with your ID card you will obviously not have a passport stamp, but you can buy something as soon as you arrive in Turkey and save the receipt.

Comment: Will your travel itinerary require you to the ROC after visiting the TRNC, or will you be flying to Turkey from the TRNC?  Either way might conceivably present problems, but to get an accurate answer you might want to edit your question to specify which one is the case.

Comment: Michael, my case is that I want to go to TRNC, but I found cheap tickets to ROC. I want to stay in TRNC and I actually don't need to go back to ROC unless I'm flying to Europe. The question about Turkey comes "in case" if I have to go Turkey from TRNC, what will be the status of my passport as I leave TRNC (because in this story, I entered the island from south)? thank you

Answer (score 2):

You should use your American passport to enter and exit ROC, and then your Turkish ID to enter and exit TRNC and Turkey.

If not intending to return to the ROC on this visit, then, when entering TRNC, ask for an entry form with an entry stamp (this will also be stamped when exiting for Turkey), and bring it with you next time you do visit the ROC, as proof you left the island.

Alternatively, you might be able to have the TRNC stamp your US passport **on entry and exit** despite admitting you on the basis of your Turkish ID, if you explain you need it as proof of having left the island. This would be the most convenient thing, and, unlike entering the Island through the TRNC, will not normally cause issues with ROC authorities.

Comment: Would you have a source for this?  Turkish citizens require a visa to enter Cyprus (ROC), are you sure you can passport-switch at the ROC/TRNC border without problems?

Comment: @jpatokal They are *de facto* two separate countries (though TRNC mostly feels like an autonomous part of Turkey), and ROC doesn't care about whether a passport overstayed, but whether a person did.

Comment: @Crazydre they are certainly de facto divided. As for "countries", it's not so clear. One of them is only recognized as a country by Turkey.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ They are *de facto* separate countries, but not *de jure*, because of the recognition issues.